# How can we import the contents of a database to another database with command in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I think first we should use "pg_dump for create a CSV file,but I can not do that.
I Have a table which name is skill_level in database=postgres and I want to import that to my database=sportner
I use:

```
pg_dump -t skill_level postgres | psql sportner
```

but I have error in SQL shell : Syntax error at or near pg_dump.

I can move the csv file to my second database with this command:

```
COPY persons
FROM 'C:\person.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
and it works.
```

I want do them just with SQL commands not with import/export in pgAdmin4.

Comment: pg_dump is a shell(OS) command, **not** a psql command. Try it from the os prompt instead.

Comment: can I use from copy?